# Text for "off-topic" on meta sites isn't quite right

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just closed a question on http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com since it belonged on the parent site.  I chose "off-topic" as the most suitable reason for closing (though explained more fully in a comment, of course) but afterwards realised that the text was inaccurate:

> Questions on Meta TeX - LaTeX are expected to generally relate to TeX, LaTeX and other related typesetting systems, within the scope defined in the faq.

Remember: this is for the *meta* site, not the parent site.  Could this be changed to something more suitable?

(And could whoever split that infinitive be asked politely not to do it again?  I'm amazed that the english.SX crowd haven't complained; also, it changes the meaning.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The off-topic close reason now reads

> Questions on this site are expected to be discussion, support, and feature requests for TeX - LaTeX - Stack Exchange.

as expected.